# Virtualbox guest additions on Ubuntu host and Manjaro guest

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, virtualbox, manjaro

I've installed Manjaro in a guest VM on an Ubuntu 18.10 host, but I cannot make the guest additions work in my Manjaro guest.

I've installed kernel `5.1.1-2` in Manjaro, and the output of `uname -r` is:

```
5.1.1-2-MANJARO
```

Then, I tried installing `virtualbox-guest-utils`, and when I do that it gives me the option to choose which provider I want to use:

[image]

And here, I enter `8` to use `linux51-virtualbox-guest-modules`, but when I reboot my machine, nothing changes (I expect the display size to be adjusted to the window size etc., but nothing!)

Is it possible I'm missing something on my Ubuntu host? I have a Windows 10 VM and guest additions work fine in that.

Comment: Are you following this tutorial? - https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=VirtualBox

Comment: Thank you @slm for your reply. As it turns out, I had to change the display option from `VMSVGA` to `VBoxVGA`. I would answer the question here myself, but I don't think I'm able to do it :(

Comment: You can answer your own Q's, that is allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I missed that :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the same question in [Manjaro forums](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/virtualbox-guest-additions-on-ubuntu-host-and-manjaro-guest/88895), it turned out that I needed to change the display of the VM from `VMSVGA` to `VBoxVGA`. It's worth noting that it didn't work on my existing machine, and I had to create a new VM with this setting.